# why my Azure web apps System.NullReferenceException

Tags: visual-studio, azure, cloud, azure-web-app-service

I have deploy my web apps to azure and also connect my apps to database that i have deploy before. i also done with the connection between the apps and database. i connect it using Linked Resource interface in manage.windowsazure.com and modify Web.config file using FTP.

but when i try to login to my web apps in azure, i face this problem .[image: Login Error Message]

Does anyone know what's wrong with my project and how to solve it ?
Thank You .
Note : CMMS is the name of my project

Comment: What is going on in the ValidateEmployee.. method?

Comment: @AlexBelotserkovskiy the method is to validate whether the username and password is exist or not in the database. i try to connect my apps to another database and it is running well, so i assume my validation method is correct.

Comment: That may be too obvious question, but did you see if everything is OK with your data in the database? The error looks like you may have no corresponding record for that user, and it throws null exception

Comment: aaaah, i see then. i made a mistake with the table that have no corresponding with another table. thanks a lot @AlexBelotserkovskiy